# Separate Hibernate library for multiple web applications

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to have two web applications that use Hibernate, Spring, and JSF 2.0. One would be the website which is available to the public and the other a content management system available on the company intranet.
I don't want to have duplicate code that accesses the database. I want to create a JAR file that contains all the database manipulation using hibernate.
I can't find any examples on the we of how this is done.
Does anyone have any helpful tips? I've managed to create the hibernate JAR file and put a test main in it and that can retrieve the data from the database. I think my main problem is how do I go about configuring all this in the web application?
thanks

---

After playing around with things a bit. I'm almost there
I'm getting this error when deploying to glassfish now
`Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BrandService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'BrandDao' while setting bean property 'brandDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BrandDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'SessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested .... msg.seeServerLog`

Comment: you need to add the jar file with the DAO codes to you WEB-INF/lib folder of both web applications.

Comment: I seems like your dataSource object is not picked up by Spring. Where do you configure your dataSource bean?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not difference between JAR was used by java console application(your test main) and JAR was used by java web application .

Comment: I've followed this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/jsf-2-primefaces-3-spring-3-hibernate-4.html and I've created two projects. The first project contains the Hibernate code, including the  model, DAO and Service objects. The second project contains the JSF and spring and has the managed bean. The second project imports the compiled JAR file of the first project.

Comment: I've deployed to Glassfish, but get the error: Cannot find class [com.xxx.BrandDAO] for bean with name 'BrandDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.BrandDAO.